# Custom javascript to check if fields are required

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a some custom validation for a small input form, that checks if a field is required. If it is a required field it alerts the user, if there is no value. At the moment it will validate all inputs other than check boxes.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <div class="ss-item-required">
      <label>Question: What is your name?</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="ss-item-required">
      <label>Question: What is your email?</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="ss-item-required">
      <label>Question: What is your address?</label>
      <textarea name="address" rows="8" cols="75" id="address"></textarea>
    </div>
     <div class="ss-item-required">
      <label>Do you agree to out terms?</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Check_0">
    </div>

    <a href="#" onclick="formcheck(); return false">Submit</a>
 </form>
 
 <script>
 function formcheck() {
  var fields = $(".ss-item-required")
        .find("select, textarea, input").serializeArray();
  
  $.each(fields, function(i, field) {
    if (!field.value)
      alert(field.name + ' is required');
   }); 
  console.log(fields);
}
 </script>
```

If anyone can work out how to include validation of check boxes, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: See my updated answer for the solution.

Comment: Use a submit button and required attribute and you have your form's validation. Any customized validation should be set inside form submit handler.

Comment: I couldn't do that because of a requirement for the style of validation messages, but yes if anyone else come across this question A. Wolff is correct.

Comment: You can style the validation messages if you use the [Validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though some answers already provide a solution, I've decided to give mine, that will validate every required input in your form, regardless of being a checkbox (maintaining your `each` loop).

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <div class="ss-item-required">
      <label>Question: What is your name?</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    </div>
    <div class="ss-item-required">
      <label>Question: What is your email?</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="ss-item-required">
      <label>Question: What is your address?</label>
      <textarea name="address" rows="8" cols="75" id="address"></textarea>
    </div>
     <div class="ss-item-required">
      <label>Do you agree to out terms?</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Check_0">
    </div>

    <a href="#" onclick="formcheck(); return false">Submit</a>
 </form>
 
 <script>
 function formcheck() {
  var fields = $(".ss-item-required")
  $.each(fields, function(i, field) {
    
    field=$(field).find('input, select, textarea')[0]
    if (!field.value || (field.type=='checkbox' && !field.checked))
      alert(field.name + ' is required');
   }); 
}
 </script>
```

The problems were:

- `serializeArray()` would try to get the value from your checkbox, and because it returned nothing, the checkbox input was never added to fields!
- Checkboxes don't have a property `value`, instead they are `checked`

Comment: Thank-you, you're awesome :)

Comment: Checkboxes most certainly do have a `value` property. Without it, checking the checkbox would have no meaning.

Comment: They do have a value property yes, but its not what validates if the input is checked or not! Edit my answer and do `console.log(field.name,field.value,field.checked)`. You'll see the value for the checkbox is always "on" opposed to `checked` that will alternate with `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to determine this:

Check the `length` of the JQuery wrapped set that queries for only checked checkboxes and see if it is `1`:

```
if($("input[name='Check_0']:checked").length === 1)
```

Check the `checked` property of the DOM element itself (which is what I'm showing below) for `false`. To extract the DOM element from the JQuery wrapped set, you can pass an index to the wrapped set (`[0]` in this case), which extracts just that one item as a DOM element and then you can use the standard DOM API.

```
if(!$("input[type='checkbox']")[0].checked)
```

> **NOTE:** It's important to understand that all client-side validation can be easily bypassed by anyone who really wants to. As such, you
>   should always do a second round of validation on the server that will
>   be receiving the data.

FYI: You have some invalid HTML: There is no closing tag for `input` elements and for `label` elements, you must either nest the element that the label is "for" inside of the `label` or you must add the `for` attribute to the `label` and give it a value of the `id` of the element that the `label` is "for". I've corrected both of these things below:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <div class="ss-item-required">
      <label for="userName">Question: What is your name?</label>
      <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName">
    </div>
    <div class="ss-item-required">
      <label for="email">Question: What is your email?</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="ss-item-required">
      <label for="address">Question: What is your address?</label>
      <textarea name="address" rows="8" cols="75" id="address"></textarea>
    </div>
     <div class="ss-item-required">
      <label for="Check_0">Do you agree to out terms?
        <input type="checkbox" name="Check_0">
      </label>
    </div>

    <a href="#" onclick="formcheck(); return false">Submit</a>
 </form>
 
 <script>
 function formcheck() {
  var fields = $(".ss-item-required")
        .find("select, textarea, input").serializeArray();
  
  $.each(fields, function(i, field) {
    if (!field.value){
      alert(field.name + ' is required');
    }
  }); 
  
  // Check to see if the input is a checkbox and if it's checked
  if(!$("input[type='checkbox']")[0].checked){
      alert("You must agree to the terms to continue.");
  }
}
 </script>
```

---

**Personally (and I'm far from alone on this), the use of JQuery is way overused in today's world.** When it came out, the standard DOM API wasn't as mature as it is now and JQuery made DOM element selection and manipulation very simple. Back then, JQuery was a Godsend.

Today, the DOM API has matured and much of what we use to rely on JQuery to make easy, can be done just as easily without JQuery. This means you don't have to reference the JQuery library at all (faster page loading) and you're code follows standards.

If you're interested, here's your code without JQuery:

```html
<form>
    <div class="ss-item-required">
      <label for="userName">Question: What is your name?</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="userName">
    </div>
    <div class="ss-item-required">
      <label for="email">Question: What is your email?</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="ss-item-required">
      <label for="address">Question: What is your address?</label>
      <textarea name="address" rows="8" cols="75" id="address"></textarea>
    </div>
     <div class="ss-item-required">
      <label for="Check_0">Do you agree to out terms?
        <input type="checkbox" name="Check_0">
      </label>
    </div>

    <a href="#" onclick="formcheck(); return false">Submit</a>
 </form>
 
 <script>
 function formcheck() {
  // Get all the required elements into an Array
  var fields = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".ss-item-required > *"));
  
   // Loop over the array:
   fields.forEach(function(field) {
     // Check for text boxes or textareas that have no value
     if ((field.type === "text" || field.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "textarea")
          && !field.value){
       alert(field.name + ' is required');
       // Then check for checkboxes that aren't checked
     } else if(field.type === "checkbox" && !field.checked){
       alert("You must agree to the terms to continue.");
     }
   }); 
}
 </script>
```